# How to manually restart Jenkins without wiping-out the Jenkins installation?

Tags: jenkins

I need to manually restart Jenkins without wiping-out the Jenkins installation. I have seen many threads, but cannot find a proper solution.

I am using a Windows server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below steps.

1. Go to the location where you have downloaded `jenkins.war`
2. Right click and open a command prompt
3. Type the below command and press Enter

   java -jar jenkins.war

Answer (score 1):

You can add /restart after root url of your jenkins instalation and it will do what you need. 
**Note:** it will wait till all running jobs finish

**Example** my.jenkins.com/restart

Comment: Not working is too general, please provide more details

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's enough when you click on "Manage Jenkins" -> "Reload Configuration from disk".

Comment: It cannot be done since Jenkins is down at the moment :(